# How can I browse catalog objects using pgAdmin-4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm connected via pgAdmin-4 to a new empty database running locally in a docker image.
I can run queries such as the following:

```
select * from pg_tables;

select * from pg_user;
```

Is there a way for me to visually browse the catalog objects,
in the same way that I can navigate through 'user' schemas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the menu `File` / `Preferences`, navigate to `Browser` / `Display`, scroll down on he right side and activate `Show system objects?`.

Then pgAdmin will display system objects.  To make things more difficult, the `pg_catalog` schema is not listed under "Schemas", but under "Catalogs".

Note that [there is a bug](https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues/5235) in this area in older versions of pgAdmin, so be sure to use version 6.13 or better.