# What are existing tables on a new PostegreSQL 15.1 installation?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I've just installed PostegreSql 15.1

Previous I installed and uninstalled it several times

After this last installation, if I try via PgAdmin to see "default" PostegreSql tables, the list is empty (see image)

I tried to install (also version 16.rc1) and unistall it several times but I'm not able to see "default table"

[image]

Comment: The system tables are not in schema `public`, but in schema `pg_catalog`. To confuse you, pgAdmin shows that under "catalogs". pgAdmin also hides system objects from you unless you configure it differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find this out using the `psql` utility (or the tool of your choice). See end of answer for a how-to for pgAdmin 4.

Run the following SQL (this code will also work on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/pxNyaNBc)):

```
SELECT 
  table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, table_type
FROM 
  information_schema.tables
WHERE 
  table_schema IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema');
```

Result:

```
table_catalog |    table_schema    |              table_name               | table_type 
---------------+--------------------+---------------------------------------+------------
 test          | pg_catalog         | pg_statistic                          | BASE TABLE
 test          | pg_catalog         | pg_type                               | BASE TABLE
 test          | pg_catalog         | pg_foreign_table                      | BASE TABLE
 test          | pg_catalog         | pg_authid                             | BASE TABLE
 test          | pg_catalog         | pg_shadow                             | VIEW
 test          | pg_catalog         | pg_statistic_ext_data                 | BASE TABLE
 test          | pg_catalog         | pg_roles                              | VIEW
 test          | pg_catalog         | pg_settings                           | VIEW
 test          | pg_catalog         | pg_file_settings                      | VIEW
...
...
...
```

and the `information_schema` (the vast majority of these are `VIEW`s):

```
test          | information_schema | information_schema_catalog_name       | VIEW
 test          | information_schema | attributes                            | VIEW
 test          | information_schema | applicable_roles                      | VIEW
 test          | information_schema | administrable_role_authorizations     | VIEW
 test          | information_schema | check_constraint_routine_usage        | VIEW
 test          | information_schema | character_sets                        | VIEW
 test          | information_schema | check_constraints                     | VIEW
...
...
...
```

Note that the exact number and/or names of tables will vary (slightly) from version to version.

and the `information_schema` schema

```
 test          | information_schema | information_schema_catalog_name       | VIEW
 test          | information_schema | attributes                            | VIEW
 test          | information_schema | applicable_roles                      | VIEW
 test          | information_schema | administrable_role_authorizations     | VIEW
 test          | information_schema | check_constraint_routine_usage        | VIEW
 test          | information_schema | character_sets                        | VIEW
 test          | information_schema | check_constraints                     | VIEW
...
...
...
```

These will appear in a clean install. You can also use "pure" `psql`:

```
\dt+
```

Result:

```
                  List of relations
   Schema   |          Name           | Type  | Owner 
------------+-------------------------+-------+-------
 pg_catalog | pg_aggregate            | table | pol
 pg_catalog | pg_am                   | table | pol
 pg_catalog | pg_amop                 | table | pol
...
...
...
```

and then, for the `VIEW`s:

```
\dv+
```

Result:

```
                      List of relations
   Schema   |              Name               | Type | Owner 
------------+---------------------------------+------+-------
 pg_catalog | pg_available_extension_versions | view | pol
 pg_catalog | pg_available_extensions         | view | pol
 pg_catalog | pg_backend_memory_contexts      | view | pol
 pg_catalog | pg_config                       | view | pol
...
...
...
```

This also works for the `information_schema`. As mentioned above, you should also be able to do this with the tool of your choice - for example, here's a how-to using [pgAdmin 4](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/316061/34007) - you can set system catalog tables to be visible by default or not (I find they clutter the interface - only switch on when necessary).